# Multiple Certficiation Authority certificates (?)

Tags: kubernetes, kops, kubernetes-security

I have created a `kubernetes` cluster on `aws` using `kops`.

Unless I am wrong, the `ca.crt` and `ca.key` files are in the following locations as indicated by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172310/kubernetes-ca-file-when-deploying-via-kops) very helpful answer:

```
   - s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<CLUSTER_NAME>/pki/private/ca/*.key
   - s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<CLUSTER_NAME>/pki/issued/ca/*.crt
```

However, I coulnd't help noticing that in my `~/.kube/config` file (which was created automatically by `kops`), I have an entry named:

```
certificate-authority-data
```

whose contents are **different** than both of the above files.

What is in any case the CA key/crt pairs we should use when issuing client certificates?

Why there are (seemingly) more than one CAs ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is weird ... (perhaps for an inexperienced on such issues like me ...)

When I perform:

```
echo -n <contents_of_the_certificate-authority-data_entry_of_my_kubeconfig_file> | base64 --decode
```

...I get my `ca.crt` file ...

Isn't the `ca.crt` already `base64` encoded?

Comment: The CA file is probably PEM-encoded.  You are then base64-encoding that. Not sure why k8s decided to have the file base64-encoded, probably because it's easy and deterministic to encode/decode it, and the base64-encoded thing becomes a one-line thing, so no one has to struggle with getting multi-line PEM-encoded strings into YAML

Answer (score 0):

The *certificate-authority-data* present on your Kubernetes config file is nothing else that your certificate encoded in base64 (It's a lot more practical to have a continuous text string for a configuration file than without the base64 encoding).

Your .crt file is encoded in RSA, not base64. RSA is a secure cryptosystem based on public and private keys (your .crt and .key respectively). Base64, is, at best, useful for formatting or transmitting already encrypted data.

Comment: The .crt file is not encoded in RSA.  It contains (public) key data used for RSA encryption, the encoding/format of the .crt file is likely PEM.